# Throwing out recursive print

Tags: ros, print

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why am I getting this after pressing "Ctrl+C"?

Warning: recursive print statement has occurred. Throwing out recursive print.

Warning: recursive print statement has occurred. Throwing out recursive print.

forever

I can't stop it!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10332/throwing-out-recursive-print./) by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) on ROS Answers with karma: 347 on 2011-06-20

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-06-20**:
nice, didn't know that :-)

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-06-20**:
Even quicker fix: CTRLl-\ to directly send a sigkill.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-06-20**:
I have seen this being discussed (and fixed) for nodelets, but for me it happens also for regular nodes. Quick Fix: Ctrl+Z to send process to background, Then "kill %1" to kill the background process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Perhaps you don't check for `ros::ok()`? If you don't, then Ctrl-C won't kill your node.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-06-21**:
Yes, spin() does the ros::ok() check.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-06-20**:
I have the problem too. I'm using the multithreaded spinner (but I think I also had it with other spinners), so I'm just calling spin(), which should to the ros::ok check, shouldn't it?